# Targetting Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard from one project

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is it possible to target Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard from one project?

Perhaps a class library, with the program logic, and two GUI apps (one for Professional, one for Standard) to interact with the logic.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using linked files.

You create the source files in one project, then add them to the other project. The trick is you have to use the "Add as Link" option from the "Add Existing Item" dialog.

Comment: Oh.  Okay.  That sounds relatively easy :P

Thanks a lot :P